Not a valid function in Taipy
I have this code block:
from taipy.gui import Gui, notify
import taipy.gui.builder as tgb
import pandas as pd
import os

def read_data(filepath_or_url):

    try:
        if os.path.isfile(filepath_or_url):
            df = pd.read_excel(filepath_or_url)
        else:
            df = pd.read_excel(filepath_or_url, engine='openpyxl')
        notify('success', 'File loaded successfully!')
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        notify('error', f'Error loading file: {e}')
        return None

def on_click_load_data(state):
    filepath_or_url = state["filepath_or_url"]
    state["df"] = read_data(filepath_or_url)

state = {
    'filepath_or_url':"",
    "df":""
}

# def on_menu(state, action, info):
#     page = info["args"][0]
#     navigate(state, to=page)

with tgb.Page() as root_page:
    # tgb.menu(label="Menu", 
    #          lov=[('Page-1', 'Page 1'), ('Page-2', 'Page 2')], 
    #          on_action=on_menu)

    tgb.navbar()
    tgb.text("# Simulation Tool", mode = "md")
    tgb.button(label="Load Data", on_action=on_click_load_data)

with tgb.Page() as page_1:
    tgb.text("## This is Page 1 ", mode = "md")

with tgb.Page() as page_2:
    tgb.text("## This is Page 2", mode = "md")

pages = {
    "/":root_page,
    "page1": page_1,
    "page2": page_2

}

Gui(pages = pages).run(use_reloaders=True, debug=False, port=5001)


However, I keep getting the following error:
Can't resolve context 'filepath_or_url' from state object
  _warn(f"on_action(): Exception raised in '{action_function.__name__}()'", e)
/Users/akash/git/tut_taipy/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/taipy/gui/gui.py:1337: TaipyGuiWarning: on_action(): 'on_click_load_data' is not a valid function.
  _warn(f"on_action(): '{action}' is not a valid function.")

The functionality I want to achieve is when a user clicks on "Load Data" button and explorer windows opens that lets user select the dataset.

This is not how the state works. The state is an object created by Taipy and is not a dictionary.
When you have defined a variable inside your code, you can get its real value from the application like this state.df or state.filepath_or_url.
from taipy.gui import Gui, notify
import taipy.gui.builder as tgb
import pandas as pd
import os

def read_data(filepath_or_url):

   try:
       if os.path.isfile(filepath_or_url):
           df = pd.read_excel(filepath_or_url)
       else:
           df = pd.read_excel(filepath_or_url, engine='openpyxl')
       notify('success', 'File loaded successfully!')
       return df
   except Exception as e:
       notify('error', f'Error loading file: {e}')
       return None

def on_click_load_data(state):
   state.df = read_data(state.filepath_or_url)

filepath_or_url = None
df = None

# def on_menu(state, action, info):
#     page = info["args"][0]
#     navigate(state, to=page)

with tgb.Page() as root_page:
   # tgb.menu(label="Menu", 
   #          lov=[('Page-1', 'Page 1'), ('Page-2', 'Page 2')], 
   #          on_action=on_menu)

   tgb.navbar()
   tgb.text("# Simulation Tool", mode = "md")
   tgb.button(label="Load Data", on_action=on_click_load_data)

with tgb.Page() as page_1:
   tgb.text("## This is Page 1 ", mode = "md")

with tgb.Page() as page_2:
   tgb.text("## This is Page 2", mode = "md")

pages = {
   "/":root_page,
   "page1": page_1,
   "page2": page_2

}

Gui(pages = pages).run(use_reloaders=True, debug=False, port=5001)


Here is a the part of the GUI tutorial that explains it.
